# Add items to hashmap in for loop

Tags: csv, for-loop, hashmap, processing

I'm trying to put items from a csv file in an hashmap. By adding items I mean categorizing them. The csv is filled with the answers from a question list. So the csv is build up like this:

```
Person     Question
-          Do you wear glasses

1          Yes
2          Yes
3          No
4          Sometimes
```

The next step I would like to do is reading the items and put the answer in the hashmap with the key being the name of the answer and the value with the amount of that certain answer.

The hashmap should look like this with the previous example I gave:

```
Yes, 2
No, 1
Sometimes, 1
```

I'm looping right now like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < dataPersonList.size(); j++) 
{ 
    // looping through the csv
    while (t.hasNext ()) 
    { 
        // looping through the hashmap
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)t.next();

        if (dataPersonVar.glasses.equals(me.getKey())) 
        { 
            // if the item in the csv is the same as the item in the hashmap
            hm.put(me.getKey(), me.getValue() =+ 1); // the value gets +1
        }
        else 
        {
            // a new item is made and gets automatically 1
            hm.put(dataPersonVar.glasses,1); 
        }
    }
}
```

But obviously this doesn't work. I'm a starter with hashmaps but really think the hashmap is the solution for my problem. I'm working in Processing. Does anybody have an idea how to solve this? If I'm not clear enough let me know!

Thanks in advance

Edit:

As requested I hereby post the full code:

```
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Map;

    HashMap hm = new HashMap();

    import de.bezier.data.*;
    int totalParticipants;
    int bgWidth = 1000;
    int bgHeight = 1000;
    int x;
    int eSize = 10;
    int opacity = 100;
    float xLocation;
    float yLocation;
    String travelType;
    int travelTime;
    int border=400;

    float dataMinLat=1000;
    float dataMaxLat;
    float dataMinLon=1000;
    float dataMaxLon;
    float xLocationMM = (5.17880);
    float yLocationMM = (52.22541);
    ArrayList dataPersonList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList dataFunctionList = new ArrayList(100);
    Point[] pointList = new Point[1000];
    float angle;


    XlsReader reader;

    PImage kaart;

    void setup ()
    {

      textSize(10);
      size(bgWidth, bgHeight);
      background(0);
      noStroke();
      smooth();

      //kaart = loadImage("map.png");

      yLocationMM = 0 - yLocationMM;
      reader = new XlsReader( this, "MMdata.xls" );    // assumes file to be in the data folder
      totalParticipants = reader.getLastRowNum();


      for (int i = 1;i < totalParticipants+1; i++) {
        DataPerson dataPerson = new DataPerson();

        dataPerson.function = reader.getString(i, 23);
        dataPerson.firstName = reader.getString(i, 1);
        dataPerson.lastName = reader.getString(i, 2);
        dataPerson.glasses = reader.getString(i, 20);
        dataPerson.longitude = reader.getFloat(i, 55);
        dataPerson.latitude = reader.getFloat(i, 54);
        dataPerson.location = reader.getString(i, 8);
        dataPerson.ownage = reader.getString(i, 14);
        dataPerson.traveltime = reader.getInt(i, 31);
        dataPerson.establishment = reader.getString(i, 58);
        dataPerson.traveltype = reader.getString(i, 17);

        dataPersonList.add(dataPerson);
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < dataPersonList.size(); i++) {
        DataPerson person = (DataPerson) dataPersonList.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < dataFunctionList.size() + 1; j++) {

          DataFunction dataFunction = null;
          if (j < dataFunctionList.size())
          {
            dataFunction = (DataFunction) dataFunctionList.get(j);
          }
          if (dataFunction != null) {
            if (person.function.equals(dataFunction.function)) {

              dataFunction.persons.add(person);
              dataFunction.amount ++;
              break;
            }
          }
          else {
            dataFunction = new DataFunction();
            dataFunction.function = person.function;
            dataFunction.amount = 1;
            dataFunction.persons.add(person);
            dataFunctionList.add(dataFunction);
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < dataPersonList.size(); i++) {

        DataPerson dataPersonVar = (DataPerson) dataPersonList.get(i);
        if (dataPersonVar.longitude > dataMaxLon) {
          dataMaxLon = dataPersonVar.longitude;
        }
        else if (dataPersonVar.longitude < dataMinLon) {
          dataMinLon = dataPersonVar.longitude;
        }
        if (dataPersonVar.latitude > dataMaxLat) {
          dataMaxLat = dataPersonVar.latitude;
        }
        else if (dataPersonVar.latitude < dataMinLat) {
          dataMinLat = dataPersonVar.latitude;
        }
      }
    }

    class DataPerson
    {
      String function;
      String firstName;
      String lastName;
      String glasses;
      float longitude;
      float latitude;
      String location;
      String ownage;
      int traveltime;
      String establishment;
      String traveltype;

      String fullName() 
      {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
      }
    }

    class DataFunction
    {
      String function;
      int amount;
      ArrayList persons = new ArrayList();

      String getPersonNames()
      {
        String output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++) {
          DataPerson person = (DataPerson) persons.get(i);
          output += person.firstName + "(" + person.glasses + ")   ";
        }
        return output;
      }
    }

    class Point
    {
      float x;
      float y;
    }

    void draw()
    {
      background(0);
      strokeWeight(2);

      x=50;
      int xText=80;
      int procentGlasses;
      noStroke();
      pushMatrix();
      scale(1.40, 0.89);
      //image(kaart, -250, -360);
      popMatrix();
      for (int i = 0; i < dataPersonList.size(); i++) {

        DataPerson dataPersonVar = (DataPerson) dataPersonList.get(i);
        if (dataPersonVar != null) {
          xLocation = map(dataPersonVar.longitude, dataMinLon, dataMaxLon, border, bgWidth-border);
          yLocation = map(dataPersonVar.latitude, dataMinLat, dataMinLat+(dataMaxLon-dataMinLon), border, bgHeight-border);
          travelType = (dataPersonVar.traveltype);
          noFill();

          if (travelType.equals("By car")) {

            stroke(0, 0, 255, opacity+100);
          }
          else if (travelType.equals("By public transport")) {
            stroke(255, 0, 0, opacity);
          }
          else {
            stroke(255, opacity);
          }
          //text(dataPersonVar.firstName, xLocation, yLocation);
          noStroke();
          strokeWeight(4);
          stroke(100, 15);
          strokeWeight(2);
        }
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < dataPersonList.size(); i++) {
        DataPerson dataPersonVar = (DataPerson) dataPersonList.get(i);
        if (dataPersonVar != null) {
          xLocation = map(dataPersonVar.longitude, dataMinLon, dataMaxLon, border, bgWidth-200);
          yLocation = map(dataPersonVar.latitude, dataMinLat, dataMinLat+(dataMaxLon-dataMinLon), border, bgHeight-200);
          noStroke();
          fill(255, 200);
          ellipse(xLocation, yLocation, eSize, eSize);
          //println(dataPersonVar.glasses);
          Iterator t = hm.entrySet().iterator();  // Get an iterator

            for (int j = 0; j < dataPersonList.size(); j++) {

            while (t.hasNext ()) {
              Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)t.next();
              println("die in de dataPersonshit is "+dataPersonVar.glasses+". En de andere waarde is "+me.getKey());
              if (dataPersonVar.glasses.equals(me.getKey())) {
                hm.put(me.getKey(), ((Integer)me.getValue()) + 1);
                }
              else {
                hm.put(dataPersonVar.glasses, 1);
                //println("YEAH");
              }
            }
          }

          /////////drawing the circle///////////////

          angle = ((PI*2)/15*1)/dataPersonList.size()*i;
          stroke(255, 100, 50, 50);
          noFill();
          strokeWeight(3);
          pointList[i] = new Point();
          pointList[i].x = bgWidth/2+sin(angle)*400; // de punt van x = 400 ( het middelpunt van de cirkel ) + sin((360 graden) / het totaal 
          pointList[i].y = bgHeight/2+cos(angle)*400;
          beginShape();
          vertex(xLocation, yLocation);
          quadraticVertex((xLocation+pointList[i].x)/2, yLocation, pointList[i].x, pointList[i].y);
          endShape();
        }
      }


    }
```

Unfortunately I can't give you the csv but I hope the code at least helps.

Comment: What is `dataPersonList` and how can you directly do `dataPersonVar.glasses` if `dataPersonVar` is a `List`?

Comment: I made a class where I store the answers from the csv in. So all the answers to the question about glasses are stored in dataPersonVar.glasses. 
So to be perfectly clear ;). If I loop through the class I get yes,yes,no,yes,sometimes,yes.. and so on

Comment: The error processing gives btw is: "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"

Comment: `hm.put(me.getKey(), me.getValue()+ 1);` should probably fix the compilation error !!!

Comment: and the class dataPersonVar contains multiple variables ( other questions ). I have for example dataPersonVar.glasses, dataPersonVar.name, dataPersonVar.haircolor etc.

Comment: what errors are you getting ? Can you list them line wise ?

Comment: @NoobUnChained it now gives another error: The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) Object, int.

Comment: This is the only error

Comment: What is the return type of `me.getValue()` ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If this would work it should return the amount of the certain answers. The question has 5 different answers so it should result in 5 items in the hashmap with each the amount of answers each answer has.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to iterate over the map to do what you seem to be trying to do. Here is an example with a similar csv as you have described:

```
import java.util.Map;
Map<String, Integer> answers = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
//String [] fileInput = loadStrings("question.csv");
String [] fileInput = new String [] {
  "1,Yes", "2,No", "3,Yes", "4,Sometimes", "5,Yes", "6,No", "7,No", "8,No"
};
for (int i = 0 ; i < fileInput.length; i++) {
  String [] line = split(fileInput[i],",");
  String newAnswer = line[1];
  if(!answers.containsKey(newAnswer)) answers.put(newAnswer,1);
  else answers.put(newAnswer,answers.get(newAnswer)+1);
}
println(answers);
```